# Scroll a node in constant distances-SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to know how to scroll a node in a given distance, for example 100 px . I have done this:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    fingerIsOnScroll = false
}
func roundTo(value: Int) -> Int{
    var fractionNum = Double(value) / 100.0
    let roundedNum = Int(ceil(fractionNum))
    return roundedNum * 100
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if fingerIsOnScroll{
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let touchLoc = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let prevTouchLoc = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
        var jump = touchLoc.x - prevTouchLoc.x
        var myIntValue:Int = Int(jump)
        myIntValue = roundTo(myIntValue)

        var jumpCGFloat = CGFloat(myIntValue)

        simple.position=CGPointMake(simple.position.x + (jumpCGFloat), simple.position.y)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I scroll to the left it moves to the right and if I scroll to the right it doesn't even move. Thanks.

Comment: I see you set fingerIsOnScroll to false but I never see you set it to true

Comment: @BotMaster I have already solved the problem but thanks for commenting :)